# Poderiam me ajudar a contar a quantidade de caracteres de uma palavra no PHP

Tags: php, funções

Bom, eu necessito contar a quantidade de caracteres de uma palavra no PHP, mas sem utilizar strlen e também qualquer outro tipo de função especifica, a questão é que não sei como posso fazer. Alguém poderia me dar alguma ideia ou se me apresentar uma ideia, poderia me explica-la??

Comment: E por que não pode usar a strlen?

Comment: Essa é boa, não pode usar funções PHP mas quer usar PHP.

Comment: pode usar empty() ?

Comment: String em qual codificação? Se não for ASCII começa a ficar complicado.

Comment: A String com qualquer valor

Comment: Explique porquê não pode usar as funções do PHP para ficar mais claro.

Comment: empty() pode utilizar

Comment: Eu estou aprendendo PHP e meu orientador disse para eu tentar fazer sem funções especificas, mas eu não estava conseguindo pensar em nada, mas agora estou testando aqui, acho que devo conseguir

Comment: Vai depender da codificação da página tb.

Comment: A codificação da página é só um input com um botão, enquanto no PHP estou extraindo o valor do input e armazenando em uma variável

Comment: E aí, conseguiu?

Answer (score 0):

Como você mesmo falou, poderia usar empty():

Para cada posição existente ele acrescenta **'1'** no contador

```
<?php
$palavra = "abacaxi"; // 7 letras
$i = 0;
while(!empty($palavra[$i])){
  $i++;
}
echo $i;
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado por ter me ajudado

Comment: Se colocar "abácaxi" vai retornar 8... um acento no "á".

Comment: /\ dessa eu não sabia. Vou tentar pensar em algo

Answer (score 0):

Você pode acessar caracteres de uma string como se fosse um array.

Obs: como alertado nos comentários, caracteres acentuados (UTF-8) ocupam dois espaços ao invés de um, portanto para detectar este tipo de caractere, vemos se o código dele (ord) tem valor >= 127.

Veja esta tabela: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec

Desta forma, o código abaixo faz este tipo de conferência, sem uso de funções PHP como você solicitou.

```
<?php
$str = "àbcÂef"; // visualmente são 6 caracteres, mas internamente são 8 (2 UTF)
$i = 0; // pointer para a string
$c = 0; // contador de caracteres
while ($str[$i]<>"") {
    if (ord($str[$i]) >= 127) // se for utf, despreza o caractere seguinte
        $i++;
    $c++;
    $i++;
}
echo $c;
```

Mostrará: `6`

(Veja o código funcionando em https://ideone.com/Gk8JFS)

Comment: cai no mesmo problema que o @dvd falou na minha resposta

Comment: @VME, verdade, mudei o código.

Answer (score 0):

[14 letras](https://ideone.com/e3cHoA)  -  [7 letras](https://ideone.com/dPWTfH)

```
$palavra = "àñáçâçí"; // 14 letras 

function tirarAcentos($string){
    return preg_replace(array("/(á|à|ã|â|ä)/","/(Á|À|Ã|Â|Ä)/","/(é|è|ê|ë)/","/(É|È|Ê|Ë)/","/(í|ì|î|ï)/","/(Í|Ì|Î|Ï)/","/(ó|ò|õ|ô|ö)/","/(Ó|Ò|Õ|Ô|Ö)/","/(ú|ù|û|ü)/","/(Ú|Ù|Û|Ü)/","/(ñ)/","/(Ñ)/","/(ç)/","/(Ç)/"),explode(" ","a A e E i I o O u U n N c C"),$string);
}

$sem = tirarAcentos($palavra);

$i = 0;
while(!empty($sem[$i])){
  $i++;
}
echo $i;  // 7 letras
```